# Remove groupPagingCentered for first and last groups compositionalLayout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I use Compositional Layout to create collectionView which its items in each section are centered (with the option of .groupPagingCentered). However, I don't want the first and last groups (=items) to be centered, but to align right and left, Respectively. So, I used section.contentInsets with appropriate leading and trailing which I have been calculated. It works well, so it is no space before the first group or after the last group. But, now the groups are not centered correctly.
What can I do? Thanks.

```
private func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {

    var layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionNumber, env) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in

        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1))
       let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    item.contentInsets.bottom = 15
        item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 0, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)
        let groupWidth = env.container.contentSize.width * 0.4
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(groupWidth), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5))
       let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    group.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)

       let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
        let sectionRightSideInset = -(env.container.contentSize.width - groupWidth) / 2
        let sectionLefttSideInset = -(env.container.contentSize.width - groupWidth) / 2
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: sectionRightSideInset, bottom: 0, trailing: sectionLefttSideInset)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Any luck with this issue?